# Comparing a part of a string. C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, for-loop, compare

I want to compare and check if a string is a part of another string. For example:
String1 = "ACGTAAG"
String2 = "TAA"

I want to check if String1 contains String2. Im using this code but it does not work.

```
public bool ContainsSequence(string input, string toBeChecked)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            Char x = input[i];
            String y = Convert.ToString(x);

            for (int j = 0; j < toBeChecked.Length; j++)
            {
                Char a = toBeChecked[j];
                String b = Convert.ToString(a);
                if (b.Equals(y))
                {
                    j = toBeChecked.Length;
                    return true;
                }
            }

        }

        return false;
    }
```

input = string1 and tobechecked = string 2.
Im new in c# so some terms may be confusing.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Why not use the .contains? input.contains(toBeChecked).

Comment: c# has a method on the string object for this: `contains`

Comment: As to why this code does not work: you only return true if **one matching character** was found, you never check if it the whole string `ToBeChecked` is found (because you return before you could find out ;D)

Comment: Yes I will use that method. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try use String.Contains()

Check it out here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Good luck.

Comment: Wow. It was a very simple answer. I never knew there was a method for that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
If(mainString.Contains(searchedString)
{
   //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're using this to compare DNA sequences :).

Maybe string.IndexOf(string value) or one of it's overloads is better for you because it can help 
you search for further occurences of the same string (stuff like "how many times does it contain the string"):  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s(v=vs.110).aspx

If indeed all you want is just to see if the string is contained, I'd also go for the versions provided by the others.

Answer (score 0):

For nucleotide sequences you probably want some [sequence alignment algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Sequence_alignment_algorithms) which has some tolerance when sequences are not equal. For example [Smith–Waterman algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Waterman_algorithm).